# String with hyphen in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a string in R (using RStudio)

```
legend <- c('Up to 5 minutes', '5-10 minutes', '10–20 minutes', '20–40 minutes', '40–80 minutes', '80-160 minutes', '160-320 minutes', '5.3-10.6 hours', '10.6-21.2 hours', '1-2 days')
```

which runs fine when I just run the source code by line. But when I source the code it throws an error

```
Error in source(con, echo = echo, print.eval = print.eval, max.deparse.length = max.deparse.length,  : 
  con:29:52: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
```

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Check if it runs w/o the `legend` line.  If so, then you probably have a misplaced paren, comma or a hard return in an inopportune place.  Or maybe a missing comma.

Comment: If that helps, `29:52` is probably a line:character count telling you where the problem is.

Comment: seems to be a RStudio issue, reporting to them

Comment: You mean it works fine from the command line or Rgui?

Comment: Well, `source(name of file)` in the command line works fine.

Comment: You should report this on http://support.rstudio.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update from the discussion posted on RStudio:

http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/3945-bug-when-sourcing-the-application

relevant portion:

> I didn't notice it until now but when starting R I get

```
Enabling Justin-In-Time compilation, level 3.
[1] 0
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
[R.app GUI 1.53 (6335) i386-apple-darwin9.8.0]

WARNING: You're using a non-UTF8 locale, therefore only ASCII characters will work.
Please read R for Mac OS X FAQ (see Help) section 9 and adjust your system preferences accordingly.
```

> Reading the FAQ I did the standard `system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")` and now it works fine.